# How to delete <li> element from HTML view and from MongoDb database from HTML view?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I am a bit new to HTML and NodeJS so I have a simple (for you) question.

I have a collection of messages in my MongoDb database and those messages are displayed in HTML view as a `<ul>`. Therefore I would like to find a way to delete a message from the database via using HTML view.

Maybe I could add some kind of "delete" button by clicking which I could delete the particular message? This of course should be done by calling "app.delete" route.

Below I am posting both HTML code and the route which should be called in order to delete the message.

```
<ul class="messages">
  <% for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="messages">
      <span><%= " Name: " +messages[i].name+"."%></span>
      <span><%=" Message: " + messages[i].messageContent%></span>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

and JavaScript code:

```
// delete Route

app.delete('/:id', function(req, res) {

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

        var collection = db.collection('messages');

        collection.remove({'_id' : ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, data) {

            res.send({"msg" : "product deleted"});
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a form to your html with hidden input values with _id, csrf(you should be using csrf), and DELETE values. Also add a input with type "submit" and a value of "Delete" or "remove" or whatever you want to show the user to indicate that the message will be deleted. Something like the following.

```
<li class="messages">
  <span><%= " Name: " +messages[i].name+"."%></span>
  <span><%=" Message: " + messages[i].messageContent%></span>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="messages[i].id">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{_csrf}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
</li>
```

Note that I didn't format my code for your tempting engine(Jade?) as I expect you can figure that part out on your own. If not, comment and I will do my best.

Comment: Sorry, it I dont understand your solution that much (: But i added a button to a <li> element and with its help i am attempting to get the ID of an element, however it still does not work. Here is the added code: <button onclick="location.href = '/messages[i]._id';" id="deleteButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Delete</button>

Comment: The code that I posted would go inside your for loop. You need to include the id of your message so that you can reference it from your delete route. Submitting an invisible form makes it possible to pass multiple values such as a csrf. What is it that you do not understand? Also, check to make sure that you are actually reaching your delete route.